# Enabling Email settings in Server

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchardcms-1.9

I host the Orchard project from local host to server.When I created the new user account,the challenge email link coming like this /Users/Account/ChallengeEmail?nonce=f%2BWi6F6562VSOQu6lwQobTj9GvJ5bVqHfGYfXRnnEcwVHl0s2X%2FQQHUzE88bwtMXui61d2%2BAm8On6ykB14IdJ3NYAewAPjSuxHnYBMvWxBClaycMjH1AYcom650kjUZK**(I checked the sent challange email box in user settings).Help me out where should I change the localhost name to server IP address.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into settings, take a look at "Base URL", and try to change that.